# 4 rows per column in Magento Search Results

Tags: magento, search, product

im having troubles making my search results have 4 products across. I am on Magento version 1.5. I have tried modifying my catalog.xml and catalogsearch.xml using this solution:

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
```

It never worked for categories, the only way I got categories to work was using the custom design tab and adding:

```
<reference name="product_list"> 
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action> 
</reference>
```

I have also tried modifying my list.phtml file with this code and it didnt work either:

```
<?php $_columnCount = 4; ?>
```

I have no idea what else I can do to make my search results return 4 products across, the only thing that has worked for me is the custom design tab and there is none for search results. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm on magento ce 1.7.0.2 and am using a 2 column right layout.

I had to use setColumnCount in catalogsearch.xml like this:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result" template="catalogsearch/result.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
             <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
```

THEN, I had to edit styles.css around line 804 and change `.col2-right-layout .products-grid {width:632px;...}` to `width:675px`  I would like to have changed it to 100%, but that created a gray border to the right of the rightmost product, which isn't how the design was intended to work.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

may be the possibles  you facing magento bug some times

That’s a bug in Magento. Refer to this thread:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/195932/

You can use “4" instead.  Try:

```
<!-- //Removed due to Magneto bug w/ Layout cache
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
-->

<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
```

or you can see detail Solution at this [LINK](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/195932/)

Comment: I really wish this had solved it, unfortunately it didn't change anything (I did refreshed cache/browser cache). I suspect it is related but so far I haven't found a solution..

Comment: Worked for me in Magento ver. 1.9.1.0. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, this code worked for me in Magento CE 1.9.

Add it to your `local.xml` and it should work. At least it did for me.

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <block type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result" template="catalogsearch/result.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"></block>
        <action method="setListOrders"/>
        <action method="setListModes"/>
        <action method="setListCollection"/>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
        </reference>
    </block>
<catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Answer (score 1):

To doing this open up **catalogsearch.xml**
in line **59** and **109** right after this line:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

add this code:

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to local.xml worked for me:

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
        <reference name="content">
            <reference name="search_result_list">
              <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>2</columns></action>
            </reference>
        </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Magento CE 1.9.2.0